# How to add post loading events to a highchart graph using a csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am preprocessing a CSV file to use as data in my chart like described in this Highcharts doc:

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#1

but I also want it to dynamically update like in this highcharts example:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

The problem is that I don't want the dynamically updated data to be random when I'm finished because I want it to pull from the rest of my csv file.

I thought the best course of action would be to add the event under my $.get(...) function like I am for my series but it won't load.

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //chart without data
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chartcon',
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg,
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: []
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            series: []
        };

        $.get('EEC_Output.csv', function(csv){
            var lines = csv.split('\n');
            var series = {
                data: []
            };

            var time = (new Date()).getTime();
            var wait = 1000;
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line){
                var values = line.split(',');
                $.each(values, function(valueNo, value) {
                    if (valueNo == 2   && lineNo < 20 ) {
                        series.data.push({
                            x: time + (lineNo-20) * 1000,
                            y: parseFloat(value)
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
            options.series.push(series);
            var load = {
                    function(){
                    var series_ = options.series[0];
                    setInterval(function(){
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime();
                        var y = 40;
                        series_.addPoint([x,y],true,true);
                    },1000);
                }
            };

            options.chart.events.load.push(load);

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        });
```

But nothing happens after the original 20 lines load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you parse all your data you could build your chart with empty series (or some parts of data if that is what you want) and then in load event create a `setInterval` function that will add new points from parsed data array.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cmk49spq/

```
  $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    var series = [],
      dynamic = [],
      chart;

    // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
      var items = line.split(';');

      // header line containes categories
      if (lineNo === 0) {
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
          if (itemNo !== 0) {
            series[itemNo - 1] = {
              name: item,
              data: []
            };
            dynamic[itemNo - 1] = {
              data: []
            };
          }
          //if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
        });
        options.series = series;
        // Create the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
      }

      // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first 
      // position
      else {
        var date = 0;
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
          if (itemNo === 0) {
            date = Date.parse(item);
          } else {
            //series[itemNo - 1].data.push({
            dynamic[itemNo - 1].data.push({
              x: date,
              y: parseFloat(item)
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
    var len = dynamic.length,
      iter = 0,
      iterLen = dynamic[0].data.length;

    var addingDataDynamically = setInterval(function() {
      if (iter < iterLen) {
        for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
          chart.series[k].addPoint(dynamic[k].data[iter], false);
        }
        chart.redraw();
        iter++;
      } else {
        clearInterval(addingDataDynamically);
      }
    }, 1000)
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var options = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'line'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    }
  };

  $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    var series = [],
      dynamic = [],
      chart;

    // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
      var items = line.split(';');

      // header line containes categories
      if (lineNo === 0) {
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
          if (itemNo !== 0) {
            series[itemNo - 1] = {
              name: item,
              data: []
            };
            dynamic[itemNo - 1] = {
              data: []
            };
          }
          //if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
        });
        options.series = series;
        // Create the chart
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
      }

      // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first 
      // position
      else {
        var date = 0;
        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
          if (itemNo === 0) {
            date = Date.parse(item);
          } else {
            //series[itemNo - 1].data.push({
            dynamic[itemNo - 1].data.push({
              x: date,
              y: parseFloat(item)
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
    var len = dynamic.length,
      iter = 0,
      iterLen = dynamic[0].data.length;

    var addingDataDynamically = setInterval(function() {
      if (iter < iterLen) {
        for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
          chart.series[k].addPoint(dynamic[k].data[iter], false);
        }
        chart.redraw();
        iter++;
      } else {
        clearInterval(addingDataDynamically);
      }
    }, 1000)
  });

});

// Emulate get
$.get = function(id, fn) {
  fn(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
<pre id="data.csv" style="display: none">Date;Input1;Input2;Input3;Input4
07.11.2014 01:20:28;0.15;0.16;0.19;0.15
07.11.2014 01:20:35;0.14;0.15;0.16;0.14
07.11.2014 01:20:36;0.15;0.14;0.19;0.17
07.11.2014 01:20:45;0.24;0.15;0.13;0.14
07.11.2014 01:20:56;0.15;0.24;0.11;0.14
</pre>
```

Comment: This is great! My data is formatted differently though so I'm working on getting the x-values to be the current time and putting about 1 second between each data point. @KacperMadej